# Android application connecting database

Tags: php, android, wamp

i want to display success or failure as toast upon comparing the data entered through the application with the database.Comparison code is done in php and i have to display string returned by php.But upon executing following code,some html file is displayed as toast.please help me

```
InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final String responseMsg2 = convertStreamToString(is);
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                  @Override
                  public void run(){
                    //update ui here

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),responseMsg2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
               });
```

Comment: Did you check your response in browser? There is multiple reason to get html page.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `response.getEntity().getContent();` you get the whole response as a string (including tags and so on). So you need to do that:

```
String responseMsg2 = convertStreamToString(is);
final String responseAsText = android.text.Html.fromHtml(responseMsg2).toString();
```

And then use the text without html tags in your Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),responseAsText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```